# Let $\Sigma$= {a,b,c,d,e} and let N = {0,1,2,....} be the set of non neg integers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Q: describe precisely a procedure for assigning a distinct non-negative integer to every total function from N to $\Sigma$. Justify your answer briefly. If such a procedure does not exist, explain why.

I have a semi solved answer:

Such a procedure does not exist because set of total functions from N to {a,b,c,d,e} is uncountable by Cantor's Diagonalization argument. So the function is $\aleph$1. You can't map N to an uncountable set.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please show your semi-answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, just revised the question and added my semi answer. Thanks.

Comment: "The function is $\aleph_1$" has literally no meaning. Moreover, not every uncountable set has size $\aleph_1$, and the question $|\mathcal P(\Bbb N)|=\aleph_1$ is not provable, nor disprovable from the usual axioms of set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks. So other than mentioning of $\aleph$1, is my answer correct? esp, the conclusion?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Isn't $\aleph_1$ defined as the norm of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: @Carlos: No. It's not. $\aleph_1$ is defined as the cardinality of all the order types of countable *well-orders*. OP: Almost, I'd change "map $\Bbb N$ to an uncountable" to be "map $\Bbb N$ **onto** an uncountable set".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general idea is right.

As noted in comments, "The function is $\aleph1$" is not meaningful, and wouldn't be necessarily true if we "correct" it to "there are $\aleph_1$ such functions". Fortunately you don't *need* to say anything like that at all.

"You can't map N to an uncountable set" sort of misses the point, since what you're trying to find is not such a map, but a map *from* the uncountable set *to* $\mathbb N$. So what you should be saying to conclude your argument is, "You can't map an uncountable set *injectively* to $\mathbb N$".

Comment: Well written. +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but the Q says, 
"describe a procedure for assigning a distinct non neg integer to every total function from N to $\Sigma$"

So, my logic is:
1) distinct non negative integer = natural number = N.    
2) uncountable set = total function from N to $\Sigma$.    

so should the final conclusion be using 1) and 2) : "You can't map N to an uncountable set"?

Comment: @user1486802: It's true that you can't map $\mathbb N$ _surjectively_ to an uncountable set, but the question asks for an _injective_ map from the uncountable set to $\mathbb N$. You even quote that yourself: "a procedure for assigning a distinct non neg integer to every total function from N to Σ" means an injective map from the set of functions to $\mathbb N$.